# How can I move my email account's folders to the folder "Outlook"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm setting up Outlook 2016. The outlook.pst is an existing file, and I can see all my old emails, etc in it.

I have to set up my email accounts, but when I do (they're IMAP) I don't see an option where I can select the target location. (I want to use the folder structure under the top level "Outlook".)
Instead for each email account I get a new folder structure like for "Outlook", with "Inbox", "Drafts", "Sent", etc.

I also noticed ("Data file properties" | "advanced") that these accounts are created in another datafile, instead of the existing outlook.pst:

```
C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\me@mydomain.net.ost
```

(This path is read-only; I can't change this.)

How can I get rid of the new files and their accompanying file structure in Outlook, and use the Outlook.pst and its folder structure instead?

---

*Note: I'm not asking how I can move the mails; I know I can simply drag them. I want to get rid of the "me@mydomain.net" folder completely.*

Answer (score 0):

Each kind of mailbox has its own folder structure, such as Exchange account, Outlook account, GMAIL account.

I suppose you add other accounts by adding accounts in current Outlook profile. Even in this scenario, each mailbox use its own Outlook profile and structure, as they are on different mail system or mail server. Outlook just behaviors as what it should do.